# Nginx or Apache for Magento 2.x

Tags: apache, magento, nginx, magento2

We are in the process of planning for a project, an ecommerce project. Client already has a working project, for some reason they decided to rebuild from scratch with some additional functionalities. Their major concern was to handle high traffic at all times, because their current version fails so.

We chose to go with Magento 2.x for building up the e-commerce project.

But really confused with which web server to proceed. NGinx or Apache?

And what are the steps to be taken care of to speed up Magento store?

Comment: I which server currently running the system?

Comment: @Shine existing ecommerce system is in dotnet tech. For the new one we are working on server requirements. Development is being set in a Digital ocean droplet with CentOS 7.x

Comment: Use Nginx properly handling the load balance.
If your website having hight traffic use aws servers.

Comment: Sorry to annoy but please explain handling the load balance?

Comment: If you are using the AWS servers we can add multiple servers based on the load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with nginx, this is faster with great performance and scalability.

Good performance guide for Magento 2 and nginx is [here](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/magento-2-with-redis-varnish-and-nginx-as-ssl-termination/).

And [another](https://mirasvit.com/blog/7-ways-to-improve-your-magento-2-site-speed.html) for Magento 2 speed.

btw You got good answer on [Magento Stack Excange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/175438/nginx-or-apache-for-magento-2-x) already ;)